# Is it possible to smoothly hide html element and remove it using css attribute selector and property display:none?

Tags: css

I am looking for the way to smoothly hide html element and then remove it at all to deny any interaction with hidden elements. I change css property "opacity" from 1 to 0.00001 to do this. The problem is that element hide, but it's still on the screen and user can hover it. Is it possible to remove transparent element using display:none without JavaScript? I tried to do this with CSS attribute selectors, but it does not work.

```
.element[opacity^=0.00001] {
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DkX3L/

Comment: You can transition opacity and visibility, you just need to use a different timing delay function. **[Worth Reading](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337)**

Comment: On my project I can change only opacity property. Also it's just interesting why opacity attribute selector doesn't work.

Comment: Then the answer is NO, I think. You cannot remove elements as you suggest. `Display:none` or `visibility:hidden` are teh only non-JS ways AFAIK

Comment: You're not actually setting an opacity attribute when you use animate. You're setting the style attribute to contain "opacity: 0.00001" Is there no other alternative you can use, such as animate's "complete" function? http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're probably already using JavaScript to hide the elements, the best method would be to use that to stop the interaction as well. But since you've asked for a CSS solution, you could use this (IE11+):

```
.element {
    -webkit-transition: 2s;
    transition: 2s;
}
.element:hover { /* .element.hidden */
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none; /* <-- This one */
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LtEpJ/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't exactly what I am looking for. I need some teh to apply css property display:none to elements with opacity:0.00001

Comment: You're already using JavaScript/jQuery to set the opacity! All you need to do is change that line of code to `$(this).fadeOut('slow');`